# Quarkus Jacoco coverage not working when code and unit tests are in different modules

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

In my Quarkus app I have 2 modules, `module-api` and `module-impl`. Unit tests for both modules are in `module-impl`. When I run `mvn verify` the report only contains coverage for code in the `module-impl`. Code in `module-api` is at 0% even though I have unit tests for it.

However, if I move api tests from `module-impl` to `module-api`, then I will get correct coverage of the `module-api` code. Why isnt it working when I have all the tests in a single module?

I have followed the official guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/tests-with-coverage#coverage-for-tests-not-using-quarkustest

Project structure:

```
|- pom.xml (root)
|
|-- module-api
|--- src
|---- main
|--- pom.xml
|
|-- module-impl
|--- src
|---- main
|---- test
|--- pom.xml
```

**pom.xml (root)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-demo4</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>module-api</module>
        <module>module-impl</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.15.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                </native.image.path>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**pom.xml (module-api)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jacoco-demo4</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>module-api</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**pom.xml (module-impl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jacoco-demo4</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>module-impl</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty beans.xml in /src/main/resources/META-INF, so that Quarkus can scan external jars.

Comment: Had the same issue, this worked for me. [Creating a jandex index](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index) worked, too